# Setting $\delta R =0$ on boundary of hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor

Does requiring $\delta R=0$ on the boundary of hyper-surface create any restrictions or problems in deriving the field equations from Einstein-Hilbert Action?

Comment: Could you add the manuscript you are referring to?

Comment: It's actually printed on paper and I can't seem to find it online. Its called "The role of the variation principle in GR"

Comment: Setting the variation (of the curvature, and hence the action) on the boundary to zero is an assumption in variational methods.

Comment: Well, setting $\delta g_{ab}=\delta g^{ab}=0$ on the boundary is valid but setting $\delta g_{ab,c}=0$ 0r $\delta g^{ab}_{,c}=0$ is not

Comment: We set $\delta g_{ab} = 0$ on the boundary. In general $\partial_c \delta g_{ab} \neq 0$ on the boundary. Since the bulk gravitational action contains two derivatives on the metric, we will in general get boundary terms from the variation. These boundary terms are cancelled off by a boundary action which is added as well. A full description of the Lagrangian formulation of GR can be found here - http://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/poisson/research/agr.pdf (direct PDF link). See equations (4.1.7) - (4.1.10)

Comment: @Prahar that sound like all the essentials of an answer.

Comment: @Prahar, I'am actually aware of  physics.uoguelph.ca/poisson/research/agr.pdf, however my question is: If I was to derive the field equation from the Einstein-Hilbert Action, but I set $\delta R=0$ on the boundary can I still end up with the usual Einstein field equations.

Comment: If you are simply asking if you could derive some mathematical set of equations from some mathematical assumptions, then my answer is - yes, you can derive the Einstein field equations assuming that $\delta g_{ab}$ and $\partial_c \delta g_{ab}$ vanish on the boundary. (You do not need to assume $\delta R = 0$, since that requires $\partial_c \partial_d \delta g_{ab} = 0$). What I am trying to tell you though is that the proper way is to _not_ assume $\partial_c \delta g_{ab} = 0$ on the boundary, but add boundary terms.

Comment: @user38032, could you please tell the number of equation you are referring to in the manuscipt?

Comment: @Prahar, Does requiring $δR=0$ on the boundary of hyper-surface create any restrictions or problems in deriving the field equations from Einstein-Hilbert Action?

Comment: I'll have to work it out to be sure, I don't think so. What I am trying to say is that $\delta R = 0$ is _too strong_ a condition. You need that. If you don't want to worry about boundary terms, you only need to require $\delta g_{ab} = 0$ and $\partial_c \delta g_{ab} = 0$. $\delta R = 0$ is an unnecessary boundary condition.

Comment: You want to require $\delta R = 0$ for other reasons, I suggest that you say so. Assuming this is true, I don't think there should be any problem with that definition.

Comment: I do think that $δR=0$ is too strong a condition too because it restricts the way we vary the metric near boundary. I actually want to study what happens if we set the first and second derivatives of $\delta g_{ab}$ to be zero on the boundary.

Comment: Prahar, I do think that $δR=0$ is too strong a condition too because it restricts the way we vary the metric near boundary, but what happens if we set the first and second derivatives of $\delta g_{ab}$ to be zero on the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at Appendix E of Wald's General relativity book. There he derives all boundary terms which appear in the variation of Hilbert's action. There are only 3 terms coming from this variation. Two of them give Einstein's equation. The surface term comes from the other term, $g^{ab}\delta R_{ab}$, which is a total derivative, as explained by Wald. By applying Stokes theorem, we see that the boundary term only depends on derivatives of $\delta g_{ab}$, but one of them is parallel to the boundary. So, if you set "Dirichlet" boundary conditions $\delta g_{ab}=0$, this parallel derivative is zero and there is only one term left (giving the boundary term commented by Prahar above). However, if you choose to put *all* covariant derivatives of the variation to zero at the boundary, that is $\nabla_a\delta g_{bc} = 0$, you get no boundary term. Finally, if you set only parallel derivatives to zero, this condition is equivalent to putting $\delta g_{ab} = 0$, giving the same boundary term. Restricting second-order derivatives in GR is not a well-posed boundary condition (as for any hyperbolic evolution system).

You can also check in that same appendix the Hamiltonian formulation of GR. The boundary term appears again in the Hamiltonian. This term depends only on canonical conjugate momentum $\pi_{ab}$, which in turns depends only on first derivatives of the hypersurface metric $h_{ab}$.

I hope this helps.